# Showing post from currentUsers wall - Firebase / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a wall/timeline that shows posts from all the users that `currentUser` is following. All users that `currentUser` is following is showed under `Users -> UserID -> Following`. Whenever one of their followers is making a post it will be added under `feed-items` with an autoID - the key (the autoID) is added to `currentUser`s `Users -> UserID -> Wall` at the same time.

Here is an image of an example from my Firebase database:
[image]

Under `Wall` as you can see, one of this users followers has made a post (the whole post is saved under `feed-items`) and the autoID of that post has made it to the users Wall.

Now I am trying to figure out how to show all the posts in `feed-items`, based on the autoID's stored under `currentUser`s Wall.

I have tried the following code, but nothing shows and when it reaches this line `print(self.updates.count)` it is printing 0.

```
func startObersvingDB(userID: String) {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Wall").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

            if let posts = snapshot.value!["Post"] as? String {
                self.postArray.append(posts)


                for i in 0..<self.postArray.count {

                    let post = self.postArray[i]

                    print(post)
                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryEqualToValue(post).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                        var newUpdates = [Sweet]()


                        for update in snapshot.children {
                            let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                            newUpdates.append(updateObject)

                        }

                        self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()
                        print(self.updates.count)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()


                    }) { (error: NSError) in
                        print(error.description)
                    }
                }

            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing right, your structure for feed-items is something like this.

> ```
> feed-items
>     -UniquePostID
>         -Post Data (key-value pair(s))
> ```

If this is the case then to retrieve data for a post use `.child(post)` instead of `.queryEqualToValue(post)`. Also since this will return `DataSnapshot` for single post you can directly create your `Sweet` object and append it in existing `updates` array.

One more thing I don't think you need to iterate entire `postArray` each time a new post is added. You should retrieve data for new post only.

Hope this helps!!